# Transition Animations on Images

Tags: swift, uikit

Good morning.
The segmented control works fine in the static state for the images. However, I am trying to add a transition (curl down) to the images under segment control, but am not understanding how best to implement the code.  Appreciate any help on this.

class images: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var segmentCtrl1: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
}

@IBAction func segmentCtrlChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCurlDown], animations: { self.imageView.image = image
    })
    
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    
    case 0:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "footsteps.jpg")!
    case 1:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "birds.jpg")!
    case 2:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "apples.jpg")!
    default:
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "space.jpg")!
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try replacing  `self.imageView.image = image` with your entire switch statement

Comment: unfortunately, replacing it with the entire switch statement results in a significant number of errors, specifically the need to reference "self" explicitly, and an error indicating that "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion put me on the right road... I played around with the `self` and got the code to work.

```
@IBAction func segmentCtrlChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCurlDown], animations: {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "footsteps.jpg")!
        case 1:
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "birds.jpg")!
        case 2:
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "apples.jpg")!
        default:
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "space.jpg")!
        }
    })
}
```